# Missing required Modules "libtesseract libleptonica"

Tags: ios, swift, ocr, tesseract

I downloaded this project([github](https://github.com/SwiftyTesseract/SwiftyTesseract)), build and took the .framework file into my test project.
Then I embed and sign that swiftytesseract.framework file like in attached image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buDj0.png)

[Xcode screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCKD1.png)

I am able to build and run my app

Now I gave this code to another developer and when he build and run the code he is getting a compiler error  "Missing required modules libtesseract and libleptonic"

here is my app code

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyTesseract

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var txt: UILabel!

    fileprivate let tesseract = SwiftyTesseract(language: .custom("ocrb"), bundle: Bundle(for: ViewController.self), engineMode: .tesseractLstmCombined)
    @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func ocr(_ sender: Any) {
        let image = UIImage(named: "sample")!
               let result: Result<String, Error> = tesseract.performOCR(on: image)
               print(result)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create module.modulemap file at root directory like that:

```
module libtesseract {
header 
"yourpath/dependencies/include/tesseract/capi.h"
export *
}

module libleptonica {
header 

"yourpath/dependencies/include/leptonica/allheaders.h"
export *
}
```